# (SELECT * FROM table) with different results for fetchone() and iterating

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm inside a loop, trying to check if a specific entry is already in a table - if it is not, I'll insert it, if it is, I'll update it. I tried to `fetchone()` after the `c.execute(SELECT * )` and it always returns `None`, but if I try to iterate with `for result in c.execute(SELECT * )`, I get the results I expect.

This iterator works, either giving me the entry I expect to find and that I know is there, or skipping entirely for the `id_str` I know is not there (it makes no sense to use this in the code since the entry is unique, so the loop runs once or never, but I ran it for testing):

```py
for result in db_api.cursor().execute("SELECT * FROM fav_history WHERE tweet_id_str=?", (id_str,)):
#do stuff
```

But, with this

```py
db_api.cursor().execute("SELECT * FROM fav_history WHERE tweet_id_str=?", (id_str,))
result = db_api.cursor().fetchone()
if result is None:
#insert
else:
#update
```

`result` is always `None`, even for `id_str` I know is in the table.

What am I missing? How can I do this check in a correct and efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the second case is that you are generating a new cursor when you go to actually access the result set.  Instead, define a variable for the cursor, and then reuse that:

```
cursor = db_api.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM fav_history WHERE tweet_id_str=?", (id_str,))
result = cursor.fetchone()
if result is None:
    # insert
else:
    # update
```

Comment: Rookie mistake. Now that you mentioned it, I can see how every call to cursor() is a different one. Thank you.